# jQuery prevent jumping of animated divisions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I have animated tabs, where on hover over link `h2` (to fire slide animation), I animate a slide effect up/down, like an accordion.

```
<div class="slideBox">
    <div class="pane"><img src="images/homepage/sm1.jpg" alt="Room" /></div><!--pane-->
    <h2 class="drkbluebg" style="border-bottom:7px solid #fff;">
        <b>main title</b>
        <br />
        photo caption
    </h2>
    <div class="pane" style="display:block;">
        <img src="images/homepage/sm2.jpg" alt="Room" />
    </div><!--pane-->
    <h2 class="current greybg"><b>main title</b><br/>photo caption</h2>
</div><!--slideBox-->
```

However, the animation does not stop. The accordion effect (slide effect) keeps firing.
Is there a way to fix this?

(By the way, I tried with jQuerytools so far, but if you have other solution, you are welcome to propose)

This is the JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".slideBox").tabs(".pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', event: 'mouseover'});    
});
```

Here is the link to what i did http://www.ixpander.com/simulation/so_issue/

Comment: The event should be `mouseenter`, but I'm not sure if that'll be any better, I've never used jQuerytools.

Comment: You should try to configure a jsFiddle on jsFiddle.net. I can't get your code to work to begin with. I'm probably not using the correct library. Using it with jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.9. but keep getting error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method '.pane'`

Comment: yes.. same error here. i tried jsfiddle but no luck as well.. will post a link to my demo

Answer (score 0):

Try with `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover` so it will only fire when the mouse first enters the element, and not every time the mouse moves

```
$(".slideBox").tabs(".pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', event: 'mouseenter'});
```

Comment: I wonder if OP is using jQuery 1.6.2 or earlier as mouseover in general up to 1.6.2 kept executing over and over as well but does not do that any more 1.7 and later.

Comment: i added a link to my demo. mouseenter somehow helps.. but issue is still visible

Answer (score 0):

I would use it with classes and css:

```
<style>
.pane{
   height:0;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.pane.active{
   height:100px;
}

</style>
```

And then I would add the class with jQuery as follows.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slideBox").on('hover', function(){
      $(this).prev('.pane').addClass('active');
    });
}
</script>
```